# Transition matrix for defined Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Consider a sequence of iid random variables
$
\lbrace \xi_n, \; n=0,1,2,\ldots\rbrace
$
with mass probabilities $P(\xi_n=0)=0.1,P(\xi_n=1)=0.5, $ and $P(\xi_n=2)=0.4.$
Define a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ on the state space $\mathcal{S}=\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$ using the rule $X_n = \min(X_{n-1},\xi_n).$
Write the transition matrix for this Markov chain.

I am fairly new to Markov chains and this is the first time I have approached a question that defines it with this type of rule. I am unsure how to approach this question and would appreciate any type of help.

Comment: I would first try to express the event $\{X_n = k\}$ as a function of $\{X_{n-1} = j\} \cap \{\xi_n = m\}$. This allows you to express the probability space of $X_n$ as a linear combination of the probability space of $X_{n-1}$, which allows you to build the Markov chain matrix.